# SQL optimizations

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, sqlite

Do servers "per standard" (1) use write-time vs read-time optimization (2) behind the scenes? For example as a result of logging frequently run queries?

Does the calculation of number of operations hold the scrutiny of a seasoned computer scientist?

[image: comparison of number of operations in read-time versus write-time]

1. I know "standard" is a wide question.
2. I wonder if there is a better name for it.

Comment: As for your operation counts, you don't tend to see much of this in the context of databases... When `T_sum + T_new` takes a handful of CPU instructions to compute, and `select Tsum` involves a 50,000,000-cycle disk fetch, comparing "operation counts" is a little too abstract to be useful. There is no one metric which equates directly to performance, and they all depend on complex interactions between the hardware, the database configuration, and the server workload. tl;dr: It's not that simple...

Comment: @NickBarnes: Yes this is exactly my concern. Having the "@memoize"-type functionality with databases could provide some very interesting speedups on that 50m cycle fetch, but I haven't seen it anywhere. Maybe there is a good project, in this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No database that I know of does this completely automatically. Most queries are far more complicated than `select sum(T)`, so in the general case, figuring out how to incrementally update a previous result is impractical, if not impossible (consider `select hash(sum(T))` as a trivial example). And even when it's possible, it's not necessarily helpful; depending on your application, trading insert performance for select performance may not be in your best interests.

That said, many RDBMSs offer exactly this behaviour in the form of [materialised views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) (e.g. in [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm#i2119766) with the fast-refresh option, or with an indexed view in [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28SQL.80%29.aspx)). As long as the definition of the view adheres to strict constraints - and your `select sum(T)` would certainly qualify - they will update this result automatically, and employ it in other queries wherever possible.

The same result is achievable in most other RDBMSs (such as Postgres), though with some extra effort on the user's part. By creating triggers on `T`, you can automatically update `Tsum`, and query it directly.

Comment: Postgres has materialized views as well - but not with incremental updates ("fast refresh"). This: http://www.pipelinedb.com _seems_ to actually do exactly that: incrementally update the results of a query. But there is not enough information (yet?) there to be certain.